# Is this question which involves undefined behavior off-topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope

There are questions where the correct answer is "it's undefined behavior" and the user is unaware of this. Those are covered by [Should I try to explain undefined behaviour?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271372/should-i-try-to-explain-undefined-behaviour)

However, then there are ["Not in my universe questions"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258731/close-reason-for-not-in-my-universe-questions) where the premise is flawed simply because the undefined behavior is part of the question itself.

This is *not* about questions which ask "is this undefined behavior" and expect a [language-lawyer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-lawyer)-esque justification.

The most recent example is [Uninitialized pointers vs NULL and 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27268378/uninitialized-pointers-vs-null-and-0), in which the user says:

> I have a uninitialized int pointer. And when printed this always shows
>   as 0.
>
> But when checked against NULL it does not pass the condition.
>
> **And interestingly this wild pointer takes value without throwing
>   Segmentation Fault.**
>
> Any explanations??

The line I've bolded is where the user is clearly expecting a segmentation fault for undefined behavior. The answerer then says:

> [...]
>
> 3. Dereferencing an uninitialized pointer is undefined behavior, anything could happen. In particular, it doesn't mean segmentation
>      fault will always happen.
>
> To sum up, exploring UB like this doesn't prove anything.

A question whose sole premise is not about UB could receive a more complex answer which has a plausible explanation for *why* the program is behaving the way it is. However, the above linked question is clearly contrived and there's no other possible answer than "it's UB". I think the current close vote "unclear what you're asking" makes sense because the question requires more detail in order to be a "real" question.

To quote [David Schwartz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/721269/david-schwartz):

> Fix the bug and the mystery will go away.

Is this question off-topic?

Comment: See also: [Should I try to explain undefined behaviour? - Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271372/should-i-try-to-explain-undefined-behaviour)

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it's off-topic in the cases where there is:

1. A small, complete example of some code
2. Some expected output/result described
3. Actual output shown

That list is basically exactly what we look for in a question. The fact the question is built on flawed assumptions cannot be sufficient to make it off-topic, in fact most questions wouldn't be questions in the first place if there wasn't a flawed assumption.

As for how to handle it I don't think it's very productive to spend huge amounts of time explaining what a compiler/platform/fate happened to do for a given problem - the bottom line is it takes a lot of effort and it's not going to be useful to future readers.

In my view the ideal solution would be to close it as a duplicate and have a canonical answer that explains why it's undefined behaviour, where it's stated that the behaviour is undefined, how to fix it and references more details on undefined behaviour. That's not to say that it's a duplicate of "what is undefined behaviour", it's probably a duplicate of a more specific question and only related to that.

If there isn't a great canonical question for the specific problem my advice would be to invest time in curating one and using it rather than detailed but ultimately futile pockets of effort.

Comment: Of course questions are built upon flawed assumptions. But the question is clearly contrived. I agree a canonical duplicate would be nice, how can you close a question with a contrived premise as a duplicate?

Comment: @remyabel: It isn't necessaily contrived. This is an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of a situation that actually happens in real code. And the explanation for this seemingly impossible behaviour is quite interesting.

Comment: @Nisse Yes, bugs happen in real code. That's about the only connection.

Comment: A real explanation to the OP's question can help to drive home the point for naive programmers that _undefined behaviour_ **really** means **undefined**.

Comment: @Nisse A hypothetical question (without context) about undefined behavior is inherently a duplicate of undefined behavior. There's nothing else that can be added. If it had more context, such as "I'm on Linux, blah blah blah" a plausible answer could be given. That is not the case here. Any assumptions the answerer makes is strictly incorrect if the question doesn't have enough details.

Comment: @remyabel: Mentioning `gcc` is reasonably specific.

Comment: @Nisse Not really. Even two ports of GCC across two different platforms are bound to behave differently.

Comment: Any new insights on this? I feel that low-effort UB questions (e.g. [this one](//stackoverflow.com/questions/40641264/unknown-behaviour-of-c-compiler)) belong to a broader category like "caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error"; problems that are unlikely to be helpful to anyone else.

Comment: Describing what some code with UB *typically* does in practice seems potentially hugely useful in practice when people try to diagnose bad code.